# How can I update a Code First application to accommodate manual schema changes?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an app that was created using EF. The problem is that I noticed some extraneous foreign keys columns created in one of the tables. Dropping these columns causes an [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Material_Id' error.

Here is a simplified version of the class structure...

```
public class Hazard
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class HazardAnalysis
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HazardId { get; set; }
    public virtual Hazard Hazard { get; set; }
}

public class ProductHazard : HazardAnalysis
{

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

The table that was generated looked like this...

```
dbo.Hazards
  Id int 
  Name string 
  Product_Id int
```

Since the relationship between ProductHazards and Hazards is 1:many, the Product_Id field should not be there. Dropping this column generates the Invalid column name 'Product_Id' error.

I've scoured the model for hours and can't find any valid reason for this column to exist.

Is there any way to update the model after manually dropping a column?  I obviously don't want to drop and recreate the database.

I've also noticed that the productId of the current product is inserted in the dbo.Hazards Product_Id table whenever a  new ProductHazard is created. Since there is a many-to-one relationship between ProductHazards and Hazards, when a new ProductHazard is created, the Product_Id field is updated with the ProductId of the new ProductHazard, which seems bizarre.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the DbSet code:

```
public DbSet<Hazard> Hazards { get; set; }
public DbSet<HazardAnalysis> HazardAnalyses { get; set; }
```

and also...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<HazardAnalysis>()
                        .HasRequired(e => e.Hazard)
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey(e => e.HazardId)
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: This looks like it has nothing to do with MVC and everything to do with EntityFramework.

Comment: can you add the code for your DbSet definitions?

Comment: Why exactly would you say it's a many to one relationship?  Your class model does not represent a many to one at all.  It's a 0..1 to 0..1, so both ends have to have a reference to each other.  A Many to one would have a collection of some type, and you have no collections in your model.

Comment: @Phil, agreed, it is definitely an EF problem.

Comment: @Major Byte, I am including the DbSet code in the question text.

Comment: @Mystere Man, I actually said 1:many, not many:1. It is 1:many because a ProductHazard can only be associated with one hazard (since ProductHazard inherits from HazardAnalysis) whereas a hazard may be associated with many ProductHazards.

Comment: @spadelives - is ProductHazard intended to be a join table for a many:many between Product and Hazard?  Because that's essentially what you're creating here.  Additionally, I don't believe you can use navigational properties of base classes this way.  You would probably have to add ProductHazard to the context, and map ProductHazard to Hazard.

Comment: @spadelives It would seem that there is some information missing. EF references Material_ID which would imply that there is an Entity in the model called Material, but I don't see it in what you posted. Does the class Hazard have any property to another class called Material? (even if it is not included in the model)

Comment: I think that you have done something that you are not showing. I have created a small test project with the classes above and it comes out exactly as expected. Pehaps you can provide some further information?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the many part of the relationship. In this case, you need to add a collection property to your Hazard object, like below:

```
public class Hazard
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HazardAnalysis> HazardAnalyses { get; set; }
}
```